# Checking and setting cookie in a function

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I wrote a function that checks if a cookie is set, if not set then it sets the cookie.

Because the cookie is not available straight away, I need to refresh the page once, so I have access to the value.

However, when I am calling the function it just keeps reloading the page. When outside of the function it works correctly. Only when it is inside a function and I call it does it occurs.

```
function getCookie (){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['ID'])){
        $cookieID = $_COOKIE['ID'];
    }
    else{
        //generate random value for cookie id
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $uuid =  substr($charid, 0, 8)
                 .substr($charid,20,12);

        setcookie( "ID", $uuid, strtotime( '+7 days' ) ); 
        $cookieID = $_COOKIE['ID'];
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0'>  ";
    }
    echo $cookieID;
}
```

Comment: where you can call your `get_cookie()` function?

Comment: in the index.php file which has a include of the header.php file > which includes the functions.php which contains this function

Comment: Check function that are includes in a right way, by example `echo 'hello';` something like that.

Comment: yes already tried that, includes are being included correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working php page...

```
<?php

function getCookie (){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['ID'])){
        $cookieID = $_COOKIE['ID'];
    }
    else{
        //generate random value for cookie id
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $uuid =  substr($charid, 0, 8)
                 .substr($charid,20,12);

        setcookie( "ID", $uuid, strtotime( '+7 days' ) ); 
        $cookieID = $_COOKIE['ID'];

        //just assign the cookie the value as if it was in the header. 
        //no refresh needed.
        $_COOKIE['ID'] = $uuid;

    }
}

?>
<html>
<body>
<?php 
  getCookie();
  echo $_COOKIE['ID']; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would change `strtotime( '+7 days' )` for `time()+(60*60*24*7)` or `time()+604800` ... but it is working for me with the refresh and without it

Comment: that throws a headers already sent error:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at **************/header.php:6)

Comment: I've edited the answer to inclue a full php page. It tests fine so you'll need to review your page structure.

Comment: @DaveAbad I’ve copied and pasted your code into blank php file. However, mine is throwing headers already sent errors, inspecting the cookies in the browser none are being set. i have this on another server and works fine.

Comment: @DaveAbad Ah i found the problem, i needed to have ob_start(); at the beginning before i could use cookies

Answer (score 0):

Check what excacly `isset` returns. From Your description seems that simply no cookie is set after first execution of this code. In FireFox You can chcek if cookie is set using `firebug` tool.

A good idea is to compare also a type of data in any `if` for excample `if(isset($some_var) === true){` instead of `if(isset($some_Var)){`. Remember that:

`$v = 0;`

`if($v == 0){  }`  returns true

`if($v === 0){ }` returns true

`if($v == false){ }` returns true

`if($v === false){ }` return false

Comment: actually do i need some sort of global variable to include it in the function? Will the function have access to $_COOKIE['ID'] ?

Comment: if Your PHP (greather than 4.1.0 as I can see in manual) version uses `$_COOKIE` it should be accesible from any point of code also in function or class.

Comment: I've checked Your first code. It all seems to be ok with it so if You having problems i strongly suggest to check PHP settings and version. You could throw line like `var_dump($_COOKIE);`, if there is right vaersion it always should be an array and if Your cookie will be set this line should throw a cookie (all cookies :) ) value.

Comment: `$_COOKIE['ID']` should return value of a cookie in any point of Your code. For checking returned values use for excample `var_dump($_COOKIE['id']);` or in case of `isset` function `var_dump(isset($_COOKIE['id']));`. This should give You precise idea what is going on.